# Greek letter emails are going to spam

Tags: smtp, html-email, spam-prevention, microsoft-exchange

I have been sending English emails using smtp settings for quite a long time with no problem. They are spf/dkim signed with dmarc implementation as well and have always tested great as not spam. I have now added Greek alternatives and I am facing this issue. All Greek emails go to spam. The spam testers return the following error.

"MPART_ALT_DIFF_COUNT HTML and text parts are different
Make sure your TEXT version looks similar as the text inserted in your HTML version"

The html text I have is identical to the plain text: https://pasteboard.co/JtUD15C.png

I have made plenty of tests and the error only starts showing after the 250 character (around 250, I have not counted exact number). If the text is shorter than this, the email is spam free with a 10/10 as usual.

Here are my suspicions and what I have tried to counter this. The html source when I manually type Greeks letter from my keyboard turns into this: https://pasteboard.co/JtUE18M.png

Is this why spam filters think the plain text is different from the html text? I tried adding encoding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the html text with no success.
Every time the 250 character "limit" is crossed, all Greek emails end up in the spam folder.

What else can try to avoid MPART_ALT_DIFF_COUNT HTML

Comment: It looks like your Greek characters are being transformed into HTML entities. Is it possible to turn off this feature in the settings, or, say, enter the characters directly in the source of the HTML so that they don't get transformed/validated?

Comment: I tried adding the text directly into the source but the characters instantly turn into html entities again as soon as I save/refresh.

Comment: what combination of (MTA, MUA, and spam filter) are you using? What you are showing is some random web page that presumably tries to email someone else, but without that information it is impossible to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

There is supposedly a **CHARSET_FARAWAY** rule that you can utilize to include foreign language inclusion in the spam filter. 
Along with a **CHARSET_FARAWAY_HEADER** that tells that even the header of the message is written in a foreign language. I guess this could help.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. The problem is I can not send Greek emails, not receive Greek emails. Is spam filter used for sending or receiving?

Comment: Ooh... the spam filter is used for receiving mails. Could you provide more details like what service you are using to write the mail and things like that

Comment: I am using outlook office 365 smtp settings in a program called beds24. On the program's side they informed me nothing can be done to fix the issue. Anything that can be done on outlook's side is appreciated.

Comment: Try using <meta charset="ISO-8859-7"> in place of UTF-8 @Gluxable